# Microsoft Graph fails when updating orderHint for a Planner bucket

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update a Planner bucket's order. To do that, I set the `orderHint` value of that bucket to be `<prevBucketOrderHint> <nextBucketOrderHint>!`. This is the only change I make to the bucket object, however, when I try to save the changes, I get the following error:

`Validation for field 'PlanId', on entity 'Bucket' has failed: This field is read only and cannot be changed`

However, I'm not accessing nor modifying value of `PlanId` and therefore I don't understand why I get this error.

Below you can find the code I use to achieve my task (note that this is a C# code using the SDK and variable `gc` is a valid instance of `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient`):

```
theBucket.OrderHint = string.Format("{0} {1}!", previousBucket.OrderHint, nextBucket.OrderHint);
var etag = theBucket.GetEtag();

var result = gc.Planner.Buckets[bucketId].Request().Header("If-Match", etag).UpdateAsync(theBucket).Result;
```

Do you see any mistake in my approach or, alternatively, do you have any suggestions on how to change the order of buckets in a Planner plan?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you got `theBucket` object as the result of another call. The API endpoint expects a patch object that only contains the properties you want to update. You are sending the existing object as the patch object. The existing object `theBucket` has the planId set which is read-only at the service.

Fix it by creating a new PlannerBucket and only set the OrderHint property on it. Use the new PlannerBucket in the UpdateAsync method.

Comment: Great observation, that was exactly the issue - thanks a lot!